# Solving an improper integral contour integral, calculated via Wolfram but in need of analytic derivation possibly

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, dynamical-systems, contour-integration

In my studies of dynamical systems I have just encountered this supposedly tough looking improper integral, which is (not really relevant for my predicament) the Melnikov function, with the integral as follows:

> $$ M(t_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{2At\pi})e^{At\pi}}{(1+e^{2At\pi})^2} \cos{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt $$

where $ \omega > 0 $ is a constant and A is a non zero real constant. In both cases of positive and negative A I plugged that integral (a function of $t_0$) into Wolfram Mathematica and got compact expressions for answers, but I am truly unable to solve this integral analytically, so I would certainly appreciate the help on it, I have no idea where to begin but seeing as how the computer could solve it then I assumed it is possible to solve it analytically. I thank all helpers.

Comment: This is begging for a contour integral.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter : Thank you. I am not too good with contour integrals and how to find this one here, also I do not see the relation with this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't worry. This site is full of integration wizards.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter : thank you for the direction

Comment: What is really surprising (at least to me) is the simplicity of the result ! As said, contour integral (I am very bad with) is more than likely the way to go.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Yes the result is simple but I do not know how to relate this to contour integrals or how to find it

Comment: I perfectly understood your point and I would really like to learn from an answer. I am sure you will receive some quite soon.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may first assume that $A>0$. One may observe the expansion
$$
\frac{(1-e^{2At\pi})e^{At\pi}}{(1+e^{2At\pi})^2}=-\frac{(1-e^{-2At\pi})e^{-At\pi}}{(1+e^{-2At\pi})^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1) e^{-A(2n+1)\pi t}.
$$ Then one gets
$$
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{2At\pi})e^{At\pi}}{(1+e^{2At\pi})^2}  \cos{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt
\\\\&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-2At\pi})e^{-At\pi}}{(1+e^{-2At\pi})^2}\cos{(\omega(-t+t_0))} dt-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{-2At\pi})e^{-At\pi}}{(1+e^{-2At\pi})^2}\cos{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt
\\\\&=2\sin{(\omega t_0)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-2At\pi})e^{-At\pi}}{(1+e^{-2At\pi})^2}\sin{(\omega t)} dt
\\\\&=2\sin{(\omega t_0)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)\int_0^{\infty} e^{-A(2n+1)\pi t}\sin{(\omega t)}\:dt
\\\\&=2\omega\sin{(\omega t_0)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{A^2(2n+1)^2\pi^2+\omega ^2},
\end{align}
$$ giving

> $$
>  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{2At\pi})e^{At\pi}}{(1+e^{2At\pi})^2}  \cos{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt=\frac{\sin{(\omega t_0)}}{A\cosh \big(\frac{\omega}{2A} \big)}.
> $$

Comment: +1. Nice job. I was doing the same calculation when your answer arrived.

Comment: Thank you for this but Wolfram gives a different answer with a sine instead of cosine

Comment: @zbigniew2015 Edited. You are welcome.